# Removing index.php in CodeIgniter using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'm currently developing a website using CodeIgniter and I recently stumbled upon a routing & .htaccess problem.

Basically, the structure of my simple website (let's call my project 'CIExample' for the sake of simplicity) is as follow:

-Home 
-About Us 
-Our Service 
-News 
-Contact Us

which I implemented using a Page controller. This controller has 5 functions which called respective page's view, i.e:

Home(), which calls the view 'Home' 
About(), which calls the view 'About Us' and so on..

Previously, to access 'Home', I would need to type `http://localhost/CIExample/index.php/page/home` into the url window, but after setting the following routes I was able to remove the 'page' (classname) part:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page/home';
$route['home'] = 'page/home';
$route['about'] = 'page/about';
$route['service'] = 'page/service';
$route['news'] = 'page/news';
$route['contact'] = 'page/contact';
```

However, the tricky part came when I try to remove the 'index.php'.
I want to be able to access the home page by typing `http://localhost/CIExample/home`.

So I did a lot of searches on CI forum/tutorial/stack overflow, and found some codes for .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

or http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/197675/#929904 
I tried both codes but none works..

`http://localhost/CIExample/home` would direct me to 404 not found page, but `http://localhost/CIExample/index.php/home` would work just fine.

I wonder what went wrongs? Is it my routes.php or .htaccess or both?
Thanks.

Note: I've also changed my 'config/config.php' file -> `$config['index_page'] = '';`

**EDIT:** 
Finally it works! 
After tweaking the config.php file in config folder and set the following `$config['uri_protocol']  = 'PATH_INFO';` (from 'AUTO').

Available Values:

```
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
```

Dunno what's the different but according to one of the comments in http://www.jotorres.com/2011/12/removing-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter/, the same code might/might not work in the production server.

Anyone can explain the reason maybe?

Comment: The code from the CI forum should work. That's what I use. You might need to define your base since you're in a subdirectory-- RewriteBase /CIExample/

Comment: Please, mark the answer that helped you. It helps out the the author and the viewers.

Answer (score 15):

You just need to paste this in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and make this alternation to your application/config/config.php file:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 4):

I have use following method, it is working perfectly in **UBUNTU**...!!

First of all verify that you have enabled mod_rewrite (you can verify using **`phpinfo()`**) in your index.php file.

IF DISABLED mod_rewrite then RUN: 
 1. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
 2. `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/defaut`
just replace "AllowOverride None" to "`AllowOverride All`" in Tag(<'Directory /var/www/'>)
3. Then please run `sudo service apache2 restart`

Ok Good... 
Now in your root directory of Codeigniter -> Find `.htaccess` file, if not found then press **ctrl+h** , still not found then create a file `.htaccess`

In `.htaccess`
Paste following code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /ROOT DIRECTORY NAME/

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Ok finally just replace `ROOT DIRECTORY NAME`

DONT FORGOT TO **REMOVE** `index.php`  from `application/config/config.php` file
Make that line like 
 `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 2):

I use this htaccess for all my CodeIgniter projects. It supports subfolders too.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yup, this one also works after I tweaked the config.php file in config folder (see EDIT above). But thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `system/application/config/config.php`, Change

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

To

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

And in your .htaccess,add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for Codeigniter 3.1.4

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags On
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 512M
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Live:

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Local:

```
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```