# Codeigniter + htaccess for index.php + subdomain not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have directory structure on my production server as:

```
public_html/www                    # www.digicreek.com
public_html/educonnect             # educonnect.digicreek.com
public_html/educonnect/.htaccess   # Same as local(shown below)
public_html/.htaccess              # contains only one line (RewriteBase/)
```

Locally my htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Locally I can access: `http://localhost/educonnect/profile`

instead of : `http://localhost/educonnect/index.php/profile`.

But using same htaccess on my server;

I can not access: `http://educonnect.digicreek.com/profile`

However, this works: `http://educonnect.digicreek.com/index.php/profile`

What is wrong with the routing? Please help.

Do I need to make any changes to htaccess for working with subdomains?

Comment: Do you have another .htaccess file located inside of `educonnect` instead of under just `public_html`? Because you should

Comment: Yes. I created one in educonnect with same content as shown in question.

Comment: I tried using same code on public_html/.htaccess and public_html/educonnect/.htaccess

Comment: And `http://www.digicreek.com` doesn't work either for URL rewriting, correct?

Comment: I am using codeigniter only for educonnect.digicreek.com and not www.digicreek.com

Comment: Did you [try searching for other duplicates of the issue you're having?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481035/removing-index-php-in-codeigniter-using-htaccess-file) That looks like a pretty good solution in case your `mod_rewrite` module is disabled.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled. I tried plenty of SO solutions.

Comment: Try to change the last line with this (just getting rid of the QSA btw) : RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try this in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, In mycase I had `AllowOverride None` in my subdomain conf file, i changed it to `AllowOverride All` :D