# CodeIgniter shows 404 not found on the server but working fine in localhost (xampp)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my config.php
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/myblog/';` other as default.

I have two controllers 
**Main.php** and **Owner_admin_nepal.php**

Other thing as default.

But every time i upload the files to server, it always shows 404 not found.

Comment: We need more clarification: have you set what URL do you type, what `routes.php` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear enough to see the problem. But my gues would be mod_rewrite. Turn on if on the server and do not forget to edit your .htaccess - [Removing index.php in CodeIgniter using .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481035/removing-index-php-in-codeigniter-using-htaccess-file)